# MahApps adding controlzex:ToolTipAssist.AutoMove programatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm adding buttons to a Grid programatically like the code below in a MahApps Metro program. This works fine and the buttons are visible and clickable.

```
var tooltip = new ToolTip()
{
    Content = "ToolTip Text"
};

var button = new Button()
{
    Name = "Button1",
    Focusable = false,
    ToolTip = tooltip,
    Content = "ClickMe"
};

button.Click += Button1_Click;

Grid.SetRow(button, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(button, 5);
MainGrid.Children.Add(button);
```

But I want to use the `ToolTipAssist.AutoMove`. In the designer you add it like this

```
<Button Name="Button1" Content="ClickMe">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip controlzex:ToolTipAssist.AutoMove="True" Content="ToolTip Text" />
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

But I haven't been able to add it in code. `using ControlzEx;` is present in the code. I've tried:

```
tooltip.controlzex //controlzex does not exist
tooltip.ToolTipAssist //ToolTipAssist does not exist
tooltip.AutoMove //AutoMove does not exist
```

So I'm thinking it has to be an event that has to be attached somehow, but which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AutoMove` property is an *attached property*, that exposes these methods:

```
public static bool GetAutoMove(ToolTip element) { //... }
public static void SetAutoMove(ToolTip element, bool value) { //... }
```

You set `AutoMove` like this to the `tooltip` in your code:

```
ToolTipAssist.SetAutoMove(tooltip, true);
```